# Why are off-topic questions put on hold, rather than migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

I posted [a question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/815880/raid-1-vs-background-copying-daemon) which a moderator put on hold for the following reason:

> Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow. – Sven

Why do moderators with enough reputation put on hold rather than migrate to what they think is the correct site?

Additionally, why can't users move their own questions?

Comment: "Why do moderators with enough reputation put on hold rather then migrate to what they think is the correct site?" because, they know it doesn't belongs to them doesn't mean they know what belongs *elsewhere*. Each site has their own scopes, and moderators are not expected of knowing the intricacies of +100 sites, it's enough to know their own site. BTW, what costs you to, well, search where would it belong? And didn't you read the message? Hint: it has hints.

Comment: I believe that my question is in the right place. I put an explanation shortly after the question was put on hold, but no-one responded.

Comment: What are your "believes" may not adapt with the site scope. Re-read the [on topic help page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Are you sure your question is about "managing information technology systems **in a business environment**"?

Comment: Yes. I emphasize that question itself is relevant to managing servers (RAIDs/Backups) in a business environment. The fact that I show a personal example at the start may have made the moderator believe that it is relevant to general home-use (Super User) rather then in businesses.

Comment: RAID and Backups doesn't automatically makes it **a business environment**. I can have a RAID in my house for my own purposes, and I certainly have backups, but I'm not business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an enthusiast class device and a failing hard drive for a personal project. This does not make for a topical question on SF.

Had I seen your question I probably would have voted to close it using this

> Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault

As to

> Why do moderators with enough reputation put on hold rather than migrate to what they think is the correct site?

Don't migrate crap.